# Message: Call to a member function result_array() on float

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to display the results of the $ distance variable to the table in the view file.
But I get an error in my script, can anyone help solve this error?
I also want to sort the results of the $ distance variable from the smallest.
Error appears in line 38, which is in the foreach function in my view file.

This is the script from my **controller file** :

```
    function index()
    {
        $center_lat = -7.2574719;
        $center_lng = 112.7520883;
        $data= $this->m_metode->tampil_data_fotografer();
        {
            foreach($data->result_array() as $row)
             {
                    $lat=(float)$row['latitude'];
                    $lng=(float)$row['longitude'];
                    // $distance= $lat * $center_lat;
                    $distance['tb_fotografer'] =( 6371 * acos((cos(deg2rad($center_lat)) ) * (cos(deg2rad($lat))) *
                    (cos(deg2rad($lng) - deg2rad($center_lng)) )+ ((sin(deg2rad($center_lat))) *
                    (sin(deg2rad($lat))))));
                            // var_dump($distance);
                }
        }
        $this->load->view('public/pencari/v_tampil_rekomendasi',$distance);
    }
```

My **view** :

```
<?php
$no = 1;
foreach($tb_fotografer->result_array() as $fg){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg->nama ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg->alamat ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg->kamera ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg->spesifikasi_foto ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fg->keahlian_foto ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fg->latitude ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fg->longitude ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: `print_r($tb_fotografer);die;` and post data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variable "$tb_fotografer" store a float value not an array, and you can not access with result_array(). you must store as an array like this:

```
$distance['tb_fotografer'][] = ( 6371 * acos((cos(deg2rad($center_lat)) ) * (cos(deg2rad($lat))) *
                    (cos(deg2rad($lng) - deg2rad($center_lng)) )+ ((sin(deg2rad($center_lat))) *
                    (sin(deg2rad($lat))))));
```

base on your view field you needed to send $data to your view file.

```
$this->load->view('public/pencari/v_tampil_rekomendasi',['tb_fotografer' => $data->result_array()]);
```

and in your view file:

```
foreach($tb_fotografer as $fg){
```

for sort you can store data in another variable like $output and put distance on it, after that you can sort with this method: usort($array, "cmp");
after all the steps you can send to your view.

final code:

```
    function index()
        {
            $center_lat = -7.2574719;
            $center_lng = 112.7520883;
            $data= $this->m_metode->tampil_data_fotografer();
    $out = []
            {
                foreach($data->result_array() as $row)
                 {
                        $lat=(float)$row['latitude'];
                        $lng=(float)$row['longitude'];
                        // $distance= $lat * $center_lat;
                        $distance =( 6371 * acos((cos(deg2rad($center_lat)) ) * (cos(deg2rad($lat))) *
                        (cos(deg2rad($lng) - deg2rad($center_lng)) )+ ((sin(deg2rad($center_lat))) *
                        (sin(deg2rad($lat))))));
                               $out[] = array_merge($row, ['distance' => $distance]);
                    }
            }
// @todo use usort for sort base on distance
            $this->load->view('public/pencari/v_tampil_rekomendasi',['tb_fotografer' => $out]);
        }
```

Comment: oh man, thanks so much for your answer. its work!!!

but, can you explain your code about variable $out[] ? i can't understand it,hehe

Comment: I store all row field and add distance to it and store in $out. after foreach() I can sort base on distance and send sorted array "$out" to view.

Comment: how to sort it ?

$sorting[] = usort($row, ['distance' => $distance]);

like that ? i got error again

Comment: Please read this for usort usage: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_usort.asp

Answer (score 0):

You've overwritten the `$distance['tb_fotografer']` variable on each iteration and also you've accessed object on array data.
Try to modify the controller like this :

```php
function index()
{
    $center_lat = -7.2574719;
    $center_lng = 112.7520883;
    $data= $this->m_metode->tampil_data_fotografer();
    {
        foreach($data->result_array() as $key => $row)
            {
                $lat=(float)$row['latitude'];
                $lng=(float)$row['longitude'];
                // $distance= $lat * $center_lat;
                $distance['tb_fotografer'][$key][] = $row; // get all of the preserved result_array data
                $distance['tb_fotografer'][$key][]['distance'] = ( 6371 * acos((cos(deg2rad($center_lat)) ) * (cos(deg2rad($lat))) *
                (cos(deg2rad($lng) - deg2rad($center_lng)) )+ ((sin(deg2rad($center_lat))) *
                (sin(deg2rad($lat))))));
                        // var_dump($distance);
            }
    }
    $this->load->view('public/pencari/v_tampil_rekomendasi',$distance);
}
```

And the `v_tampil_rekomendasi` view like this :

```php
<?php
$no = 1;
foreach($tb_fotografer as $fg){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg['nama'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg['alamat'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg['kamera'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fg['spesifikasi_foto'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fg['keahlian_foto'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fg['latitude'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fg['longitude'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fg['distance'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't know exactly your requirements so I just supplied all of the arrays